# Query from a multi line textbox

Tags: ms-access

I have a table called A5K with a few columns, Most important being Location and Serial number

I have a split form with a multi line textbox and a search button. If I type in any location or serial number and click search. The record would appear in the datasheet form below.

What I'm trying to do is to search for multiple serial numbers/location at a time and these would appear in the datasheet.

For example, lets say I'm searching for location A,B,C&D, I would like to enter these into the multiline textbox as

```
A
B
C
D
```

Click search
and records A,B,C&D would all appear.

Comment: Will your data actually be single letter values?

Comment: Hi Andre, The values will either be 6 digit number 123456 or combination of letters and numbers (always 6 or less characters), i,e MV001 or AAV001

Comment: You have only 1 textbox for input of either locations or serials? Are both fields text type?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but is poor design. VBA code would have to build comma separated parameter array for use with IN() function. If the field type is text, also need apostrophe delimiters. Consistency of structure is critical in string manipulation. If the items are ALWAYS typed with a single CrLf between them:

```
Me.Filter = "Location IN('" & Replace(Me.textboxname, vbCrLf, "','") & "')"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: This is the current condition set on my button.                                                                   [A5K]![Location] Like "*" & [Forms]![Surcharge and Plan Change]![Text14] & "*"                              But If I have 2 lines in my textbox then this condition is not satisfied, anyway I can change this condition to look for each line? Basically using my multi line textbox as a  filter

Comment: Okay, instead of replacing a space, replace vbCrLf. See edited answer.